# How to get value of a prototype method from one javascript file to another javascript file's prototype method?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm learning Javascript and testing using Jasmine. I have 2 files. There are more details to the files. This particular section is not working. When I run the test, it fails saying "Expected NAN to equal 10". I wanted to get the totalCount from Counter.js to calculate of MyProject.js, then it is divided by iteration. Can anyone help me with this?

Counter.js

```
function Counter(){
this.count = 0;
}
Counter.prototype.startCount = function(count){
this.count += count;
};
Counter.prototype.totalCount = function(){
return this.count;
}
```

MyProject.js

```
function MyProject() {
this.iteration = 0;
}
MyProject.prototype.addIteration = function(iteration) {
this.iteration += iteration;
}
MyProject.prototype.calculate = function() {
var averageCount = Counter.prototype.totalCount();
return averageCount/this.iteration;
}
```

MyProject_spec.js

```
describe("MyProject", function() {
var project, iteration1, iteration2, iteration3;
beforeEach(function(){
project = new MyProject();
iteration1 = new Counter();
iteration1.startCount(10);

iteration2 = new Counter();
iteration2.startCount(20);

iteration3 = new Counter();
iteration3.startCount(10);
});
it("can calculate(the average number of counting completed) for a set of iterations", function(){
project.addIteration(iteration1);
expect(project.calculate()).toEqual(10);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run the test, it fails saying "Expected NAN to equal 10"

Your problem is `addIteration` is expecting a **number** as an argument and you are passing the `Counter` to the same.

```
project.addIteration(iteration1);
```

You need to modify your MyProject in such a way that

```
function MyProject() 
{ 
    this.allIteration = [];
    this.totalIterationCount = 0;
}
MyProject.prototype.addIteration = function(iteration) 
{
    this.allIteration.push( iteration ); 
    this.totalIterationCount += iteration.totalCount(); 
}
MyProject.prototype.calculate = function() 
{
    return this.totalIterationCount /this.allIteration.length;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function Counter() {
  this.count = 0;
}
Counter.prototype.startCount = function(count) {
  this.count += count;
};
Counter.prototype.totalCount = function() {
  return this.count;
}

function MyProject() {
  this.allIteration = [];
  this.totalIterationCount = 0;
}
MyProject.prototype.addIteration = function(iteration) {
  this.allIteration.push(iteration);
  this.totalIterationCount += iteration.totalCount();
}
MyProject.prototype.calculate = function() {
  return this.totalIterationCount / this.allIteration.length;
}

project = new MyProject();
iteration1 = new Counter();
iteration1.startCount(10);
iteration2 = new Counter();
iteration2.startCount(20);
iteration3 = new Counter();
iteration3.startCount(10);
project.addIteration(iteration1);
console.log(project.calculate());
project.addIteration(iteration2);
console.log(project.calculate());
project.addIteration(iteration3);
console.log(project.calculate());
```